# Immigration for International travel to US followed by domestic connection

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit, international-travel

A friend of mine is traveling to US on visitor visa. First stop is at New York followed by connection to Albuquerque, NM. Where does immigration for an international traveler need to be done in this case - New York or Albuquerque?

Comment: Where are they flying from? If there is no pre-clearance facility at the originating airport of their flight to U.S., the immigration formalities are done at the first point of entry (New York).

Comment: How could immigration take place in Albuquerque?  How would the immigration officers in Albuquerque know which passengers on the flight from New York need to be inspected and which do not?